# Make Categories a Dropdown Menu in Media Library

Tags: functions, categories, taxonomy, media-library, dropdown

I would like the categories menu to appear as a drop-down in both the list mode and grid mode view of the Wordpress media library. As of now, it only appears as a drop-down in list mode.

**List Mode - Correct** (categories appear as drop-down):

[image: List Mode]

**Grid Mode - Incorrect** (categories appear as text field):

[image: Grid Mode]

Here is the code I'm using in functions.php, which does work. I'm just not sure how to force the drop-down appearance in both view modes:

```
function add_categories_to_attachments() {
    register_taxonomy_for_object_type( 'category', 'attachment' );
}
add_action( 'init' , 'add_categories_to_attachments' );
```

Comment: Can you ellaborate further what you mean by "grid mode"?

Comment: @TomJNowell OP is referring to the media library's grid view which can be toggled using the bar at the top left of the media library when viewing all media. For some reason, when this view was implemented, the devs didn't incorporate the standard categories meta box into the backbone template, and instead displayed the categories UI as a simple text box with comma separated IDs.